# How to select images in array to fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
var n=0;
var images=["FullSizeRender (1).jpg","IMG_1875.JPG","IMG_4665.JPG","IMG_5213.JPG"];

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 // Change image
 
 $("#himg").click(function(){
  n++;
  
  if(n==images.length){
   n=0;
  };
  
  document.getElementById("himg").src=images[n];
  
  $("#himg").find('img[src="' + images[n] + '"]').fadeOut();
  $("#himg").find('img[src="' + images[n+1] + '"]').hide().fadeIn();
  
 });
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-2">
 <div id="handbags">
  <h4>Handbags</h4>
         <img id="himg" src="FullSizeRender (1).jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```

I have made an array where images change on click, but I am trying to make the images fade on click instead of sharply changing. I've tried selecting the images by source using the index from the array, but it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "select" the images? you basically want to:
1. fade out one image and then
2. fade in the new one?

or do you want them to fade out/in at the same time?

Comment: I want to fade out one then fade in the other. The problem is selecting the images in the array @jayongg.

Comment: why doesn't the solution that Night wrote below work? It's not clear what you mean by select.  You look like you are indexing into the array correctly above. `images[n]` and `images[n+1]` to get select the images at the appropriate indexes in the array.

Comment: I tried his solution, unfortunately it didn't work with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    var images = ["FullSizeRender(1).jpg","IMG_1875.JPG","IMG_4665.JPG","IMG_5213.JPG"];
    var image = $('#himg');

    image.on('click', function() {
        var newN = n+1;
        if (newN >= images.length) { newN = 0 };
        image.attr('src', images[n]);
        image.fadeOut(300, function () {
            image.attr('src', images[newN]);
            image.fadeIn();
            n = newN;
        });
    });
});
```